# How to pass a variable in Json object while giving HTTP post request in Python

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to pass a json object to one of my URLs which accepts the JSON data.

The code below works:

```
import requests

import json

payload='{"message": "hello"}'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

r.text is giving me "hello"

But when I tried to pass the variable

```
s="hello"
payload='{"message":' +str(s)+ '}'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

The above didnt work. When I tried to load as a JSON, it is throwing me error as well

```
payload=json.loads(payload)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 12 (char 11)
```

Also I wanted to pass b'blahblah' as a JSON message. Since passing a string didnt work for me, I didnt attempt to pass bytes format.

Please advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include double quotes around the string in your JSON object:

```
payload='{"message":"' +str(s)+ '"}'
```

so that `payload` would become `'{"message": "hello"}'`.

Otherwise `payload` would become `'{"message": hello}'` with your current code.

Comment: I dont know why this was down voted. This worked for me :) . Is it possible to send the bytes in JSON object ? For me the image is going to be my JSON. Is there any way to send bytes to JSON?

Comment: JSON is meant for texts. You can encode images into texts with [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) if you insist though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.dumps`:

```
payloads = {"message": s}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payloads), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

rec is the variable whose value I wanted to print

```
url = "abc.com"
payload = '{"text":"' +str(rec)+ '"}'
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
```